# HTTP Not Modified 304, why does the server not work as expected?

Tags: server, http-headers, browser-cache

I have worked with a few web projects. So obviously this involves CSS, JS and Image files.
Correct me if my understanding of caching, written below is wrong.
According to the way caching of these files work, the browser asks the server if any of the requested files has been modified since it last fetched them. The server is supposed to send the file if it was modified else just send a 304 Not Modified response.

Why do we even have to use the hacks like changing the image file names or adding versions / timestamps -

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css?v3.x" />
>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css?1462282900307" />

How can I not use these hacks and ensure that I do not have to ask people to hit `Ctrl + F5` if the file was modified?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664800/best-way-to-control-browser-caching-of-changing-js-and-css-files-in-apache/34672116#34672116

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different caching instructions that a server can issue.

One of them is "This file expires on date X". Given that, the client won't spent time asking the server if the file has been updated, it will just trust that it hasn't. This saves a HEAD request for each time the client encounters a request for that URL.

If you want the client to check, with a HEAD request, every time: Use a `Last-Modified` header and don't use `Expires` or `Cache-Control`.