# How to say browser to reload new version of images

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I have versioned JS a CSS files and it works very well.
.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

php function:

```
/**
 *  Given a file, i.e. /css/base.css, replaces it with a string containing the
 *  file's mtime, i.e. /css/base.1221534296.css.
 *
 *  @param $file  The file to be loaded.  Must be an absolute path (i.e.
 *                starting with slash).
 */
function auto_version($file)
{
  if(strpos($file, '/') !== 0 || !file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file))
    return $file;

  $mtime = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);
  return preg_replace('{\\.([^./]+)$}', ".$mtime.\$1", $file);
}
```

and used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo auto_version('/css/base.css'); ?>" type="text/css" />
```

Now i have problem with images in css files which are not reloaded when new css is reloaded.
For example css content:

```
.mysprite {
    background: transparent url("../mysprite.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

How to force the browser to reload also new images?
There are many and many images in my other css files and it is not possible to change their random name in css like JS and CSS filenames.

I tried in htaccess this:

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

but no help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to control browser caching of changing js and css files in apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664800/best-way-to-control-browser-caching-of-changing-js-and-css-files-in-apache)

Comment: "but then is problem with dynamic content generated from PHP" - what does that mean? How does this affect the CSS file?

Comment: @NicoHaase this is about images.

Comment: change "../mysprite.svg" to "../mysprite.svg?v=1", but you have to change the v=1 to v=2 when you change the images.

Comment: "../mysprite.svg?v=1" not work as not work for js and css files. Browser means that its same file. As I said before I can not change huge of url`s of images in css files. Its impossible.

Comment: "Browser means that its same file" - what do you mean by that? What exactly is not working in the same way as for CSS or JS files? Before requesting them, the browser does not know whether they are the same file or not

Comment: @avia please share more details. Even if this is about images, what's the difference?

Comment: @NicoHaase simply as I think this technique works for JS and CSS files but not image assets? I might be wrong.

Comment: Why shouldn't it work in the exact same way? What could be the problem? Have you tried it out to check whether this works?

Comment: "../mysprite.svg?v=1"  Yes it works, at least for CSS and JS files. I never tried with images.

Comment: I had the v=1 solution working for a long time before I recently found out that the browser started ignoring it.
But it doesn't matter anyway, because in my case it's impossible to change the url for images in all css files with each version. There's no point in dealing with that.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the headers to force reloading all resources, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
```

If you want a maximum of compatibility you can go all out with something like this

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense if the sources aren't cached.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Wouldn't this bypass the cache in **all** cases?

Comment: What do you mean *are not cached*? This is precisely the question here, no? "How to force the browser to reload also new images?" (New as in 'new versions of images with the same filename already stored in cache"?)

Comment: @NicoHaase yes this is a hardcore no-cache solution for all assets, indeed.

Comment: To me, that does not sound like a good approach. Usually, media assets use a lot of data, and not caching them at all would lead to way higher loading times

Comment: @NicoHaase indeed, it would. It would probably be best to rename all concerned assets programatically in the storage filesystem and in the CSS, but OP does not wish to do that.